# Scala: does sbt also execute installed modules?

Tags: scala, sbt, dependency-management

I'm wondering how this works in Scala.

In Ruby e.g. I use bundler to install gems which can then be executed by running either `bundle exec <gem>` if they were installed project-wide or just `<gem>` when it was installed globally.

What is the equivalent in Scala? Is it sbt? How does it work?

Thanks.

Comment: SBT is managing libraries, not executables

Answer (score 0):

SBT doesn't do this indeed, but there's something in Scala land that comes quite close to what you want. It's called [Coursier](https://github.com/alexarchambault/coursier), and it can fetch and run Maven/Ivy dependencies, besides its other tasks. Particularly, [launch](https://github.com/alexarchambault/coursier#launch) section in the documentation might be of interest to you.